# How can I add a piece of timber to my metal shed wall without creating a leak?

Tags: leak, waterproofing, shed, steel

I have a garden shed with steel (powder coated) walls. I'd like to attach a piece of timber to the inside of the wall. I'll use the timber to attach hooks for hanging tools.

I don't want the holes I put in the wall to create a leak, and I don't know the best technique to use to prevent it leaking. The shed doesn't have eaves.

2 or 3 bolts through the timber and the shed wall would probably be sufficient when it comes to strength. Would some silicone sealant around the bolts stay watertight for a few years? Is there a better way of preventing water leaking through the bolt holes, or a better way of securing the timber?

In case it matters, temperatures in my location range from -5 to 35 C

Answer (score 5):

I would use some neoprene washers between the exterior bolt head and metal wall.  Also put some silicon sealant in the hole/bolt. This will keep water out and stop bolt head from scratching the powder coating and causing rust. Should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of through bolting get 3 or 4  3/4" disc Neodymium magnets and cement them to that 2x4. each having 20# of pull should more than adequate to hang most tools from. Plus you can re position the hanger and no holes in shed

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way to fabricate some hooks that can go over the walls where the roof and walls meet. I am thinking of several pieces of 1/8" by 1" flat stock bent into a "J" shape to which you could attach a 2x4. Then install hooks in 2x4 to hang the tools on.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Liquid Nails]

I would try construction adhesive before drilling any holes in the wall.

The MSDS for [Liquid Nails](http://www.duspec.com/DuSpec2/product/ProductDocumentSearchController.htm?documentFormat=pdf&systemSetId=70&productCode=LN-903&documentType=datasheet) states that the shear strength is 240 psi (1 week cure), and will withstand -18 to 60 C.  Should be more than sufficient.